# How to enable Elgg Web Services

Tags: elgg

How to enable Elgg Web Services?
I found [this link](http://blog.arvixe.com/web-services-api-in-elgg/) but it is outdated because tick Enable Web Services doesn't exist. Please provide screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web services have been moved to their own plugin, so go to Admin > Plugins, find Web services and enable it.